# Java - How to compare only one variable value with its previous value?

Tags: java, oop

I am working on simple Java application. The application should able to compare the variable value. For example, inside my `class A`, there is one variable called `alt_value`.

So, this `alt_value` is getting this value from a drone(I manage to get the value from drone now). All I need to do is compare the current `alt_value` with its previous value. In case the current `alt_value` is higher than the previous value, it should show "Going Up!" or vice versa.

How could this to be done? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Show your code which you tried to do this operation

Comment: Can u change class A? Then the simpliest solution would be save 2 values inside your object (active and old). Otherwise work with Observeables/ValueChangeListener

Comment: Hint: without looking at your code; it might be helpful for you to think about the question: "how many variables do I need when I want to be able to compare two values. one or two?"

Answer (score 2):

somtehing like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] test = {"A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
        String prev = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
            if (test[i].equals(prev)){
                System.out.println("equals: " + prev);
            }
            prev = test[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain two variables inside your class. One for new value and other for old value. Whenever you get new value compare it with variable having previous value.

Comment: Not necessary. Storing just before obtaining new value should suffice, what say, like the way I proposed?

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable "`alt_value`" private and create a setter "`setAlt_value( .. )`". In setter compare for existing value in `alt_value` and new value you are getting as parameter in `setAlt_value()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following when u set the new value.

```
class Foo{
 int alt_value;
 String status;

 //setter for the alt_value will be called to set new value
 void setAltValue(int new_alt_value){
      if(new_alt_value > alt_value){
          status = "Going up";
      }
      this.alt_value = new_alt_value;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this:

```
  class A {
    private int alt_value = 0;

    public int getAlt_value() {
      return alt_value;
    }

    public void setAlt_value(int alt_value) {
      this.alt_value = alt_value;
    }

    public boolean compare(int value) {
      boolean goingUp = value > alt_value;
      alt_value = value;
      return goingUp;
    }
  }
```

Then you cann call:

```
A instance = new A();
if (instance.compare(4)) {
  // show "Going Up"!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one temporary variable to store the previous value. Some thing like this should work for you

```
prev_alt_value = alt_value;
alt_value = droneMethodCall();
if(alt_value > prev_alt_value)
    System.out.println("Going Up!");
```